# SetTime out for command using Php & c++

Tags: php

i want to make a setTimeOut for a command in php so when i use `proc_open` i can control the command during execution but if this command waits fr user input it can not be terminated after a specific amount of time

**C++**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    cout << x;
    return 0;
}
```

then i compile this file and get a `programe.exe` file to make the php script run this executable and terminate after 5 seconds

**test.php**

```
<?php

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
   2 => array("file", "error-output.txt", "a") // stderr is a file to write to
);
$time = time();
$process = proc_open("programe.exe", $descriptorspec, $pipes);
    while($s= fgets($pipes[1], 1024)) 
    {
        echo $s;

        if(time()-$time>5){
            //proc_close($process);
            system("taskkill /im programe.exe /f");
            break;
        }
    }
//proc_close($process);
echo "bye";

?>
```

when i run `php test.php` it should run the script and terminate after 5 seconds but what happened is that it never close the script if i changed the c++ code to

```
while(true)
{
    cout<<"Hello";
}
```

it works successfully and terminate after 5 seconds

Comment: When a program in blocked waiting for input, it's blocked on a much lower-level (by the kernel actually) than when doing a simple busy-waiting loop.

Comment: i want to know how to break the script if he waits for input